# Is it possible to test two funnels in Content Experiments?

Tags: paypal, google-analytics, analytics, content-experiments

I am looking for some help from you regarding a test that I ran.

Although I checked tons of websites and articles about Content Experiment I didn't find the answer to my questions.

Here is the fact. 
I ran a test in Content Experiments where I test a funnel against other funnel, basically a new version of a website against the old version.

Funnel 1:
Homepage 1 => Select product 1 => Add to cart 1 => Checkout page 1 => Payment with card or PayPal 1 => Thank you 1 or Thank you page for PayPal

Funnel 2:
Homepage 2 => Select product 2 => Add to cart 2 => Checkout page 2 => Payment with card or PayPal 2 => Thank you 2 or Thank you page for PayPal (same as above)

We set up a final Goal using REGEX. It tracks the visits to all Thank you pages.

The result was that Funnel 1 converts better, but I have some doubts because:
- funnel 2 looks much better (optimized for conversions)
- I checked the conversion rates between the steps (e.g. from Homepage to Select product etc.) and funnel 2 performs better except the last step.

In the first place is it possible to test funnels in Content Experiments or just a single landing pages?

I consider myself the test to be perfectly valid, but I want to hear second opinions. Moreover, does the PayPal payments influence the conversions, considering that we use the same PayPal account for both funnels and it redirects to the same Thank you page for both?

If you had experiences like this please share your thoughts.

Best,
Mihnea

Answer (score 0):

I have found a reference on Google Support - https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1745214

It's not much, but it says you can test two paths and not only single landing pages.